# Subscribe to changes to a part of the router URL

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Say I have a link localhost:4200/details/1
I want to subscribe only to changes in the "details" part of the URL. i.e. when "details" changes to some other word and not the other parts of the URL.
How do I do it?

Edit:
So I have found a way but I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it. For some reason ActivatedRoute properties aren't holding any values(either empty or undefined). So I had to use Router.

```
currentSection: string;
constructor(private router: Router){
      router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd &&
          router.url.split('/')[1] != this.currentSection),
      )
      .subscribe((val) => {
        console.log(this.currentSection, router.url.split('/')[1]); 
        this.currentSection = router.url.split('/')[1];
      });
}
ngOnInit(){
 this.currentSection = this.router.url.split('/')[1];
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information

Comment: @JamesD No. I don't want to get the route information. I just want to subscribe to changes to that 1 word of the URL in one component.

Answer (score 1):

You have to

1. Subscribe to all changes
2. Map to required property
3. use `distinctUnilChanged` operator

eg.

```
private route:ActivatedRoute
    this.route.params.pipe(
      map(params => params.yourParamName),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(changedParam => console.log(`reacting to single param change ${changedParam}`));
```

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss I don't want it to be based on the name. I want it to be based on the 2nd part of the URL(i.e. URL.split('/')[1]). In other words it must be kinda index based.

Comment: The thing is that angular router provides a way to do it by name. If that is not suitable for you for whatever reasons, adopt solution to use url changes and analyze url in your own discretion to suit your needs. FYI route contains `segments` which is alreadly split as you would like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the activatedRoute url, and just get the first segment. Ref. [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tour-of-heroes-example-vgn4hw?file=app/hero-detail.component.ts) -> hero-detail.component.ts

You can track changes to this between components by implementing a service to which you pass the path.

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
//.....

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.url.subscribe(m =>console.log(m[0].path)) // this logs "detail"
  }
//....
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @JamesD For some reason any ActivatedRoute property isn't printing anything. It's either printing blank or undefined. Not sure why.

Comment: is the route object also empty? If not, what's the result of
```this.route.url.subscribe(m =>console.log(m))```

Comment: Its displaying [UrlSegment] but on expanding, all its properties are empty. Parameters: {} path: "" parameterMap: params: {} keys: Array(0)